# Referer Tracking For Social Media Websites ( Facebook, Twitter, Google+ ) in php

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-analytics

Is there any other way in php to track a referrer site besides `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, it seems all the social media sites have removed it, I want to know just a domain name from where user comes from. Or should I use `Google Analytics` for that ??

Thanks

Comment: Google Analytics uses the same referer field from the http headers (unless there are campaign parameters etc), so that would change nothing.

Comment: so whats the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it appears to be removed because Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ have all become full HTTPS sites and browsers will not include the Referer request header when navigating from an HTTPS page to a non-HTTPS page.

If you use https:// urls to link to your PHP site (and your site supports HTTPS) you should find the referrer data is available.

There is also a specification in draft to allow sites to control sending the Referer header at a more granular level. This will be controlled by the source site though, not the destination: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/